# Finding an object(s) within an array with specific letter using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

So I'm trying to create a method that takes an Array and a letter as arguments and returns a new array of the words that contain that letter.

I have this thus far:

```
def finder(array, thing_to_find)
  find = array.keep_if {|x| x.include?(thing_to_find)==true}
   return find
end
```

When I run the program in Ruby, it's saying the .include? is not a valid block method.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write more simple way -

```
def finder(array, thing_to_find)
  array.select { |word| word.include? thing_to_find }
end
```

`array` will pass each element `word` from that `array` to the block in each iteration. Now `word.include?(thing_to_find)` will be evaluated - If it returns `true`, then `word` will be selected and stored to an *temporary* array, otherwise not. Once all iterations will be completed with respected to the `array`, then all selected elements from each block execution, which were being stored inside a *temporary* array, that array will be returned.

Comment: Thanks Arup, can you explain why my code doesn't run?

Comment: @Lasonic.. I don't know what did you mean. Your code is too much _ugly_, but for me it is working. I didn't notice any error.